# Play jQuery based animation intro only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple animation based on jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut - it just shows some elements and hides others sequentially when a visitor loads main page of the site. So, I use this animation only on one page. I only want this to be shown one time per session so that when user clicks "Home", this wouldn't show up any more, just skipped. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can implement it with a cookie.
check if the user has the cookie, if(yes) then don't run the animation, else, do show.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Cookies and HTML5 Storage.

Html 5 storage can be used with the plugin `JStorage`

Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($.JStorage.get('intro_played') == false)
  {
     //Play the sexyness.
  }
});
```

Theres also a cookie plug-in that works in exactly the same way apart from he data is stored differently on user end.